# why manage exception even I respect the writing of fields

Tags: symfony

I try to update user, I authenticate, when I click on send it handles the exception even I respect the format of username, it gives me error:

```
"username: this field is not respect the pattern\nusername: ce champ ne doit pas avoir plus de 10 chars",

/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"get","post"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^[a-z]+$/i", message="this field is not respect the pattern")
     * @Assert\Length(min=5, max=10, minMessage="ce champ doit avoir au moins {{ limit }} chars",maxMessage="ce champ ne doit pas avoir plus de {{ limit }} chars")
     */
    private $username;
```

data send in body format json

```
{
    "username": "najib mar",
    "email":"najimard1@gmail.com",
    "name":"najib naj1",
    "password": "123456",
    "retypePassword": "123456"
}
```

Comment: There is no whitespace in your regex pattern.

Comment: even I erased the space it gives me the same error

Comment: The data sent by request is a thing, the value that's validated could be another. I would debug to get the exact value of `username` before the validation process.